# cygEGL-1.dll already occupied

Tags: matplotlib, cygwin

I am trying to install `matplotlib` on Cygwin but at the installation I get an error:

```
0 [main] python2.7 2968 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cygEGL-1.dll' (0x420000) is already occupied
```

I already tried to kill all the processes, reboot my PC and rebaseall. It does not help.

Here is the complete log:

```
$ python setup.py install
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.3]
                python: yes [2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)  [GCC
                        4.8.3]]
              platform: yes [cygwin]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.7.2]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.7.3]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                        it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.3]
                 pycxx: yes [Using system CXX (version unknown, no pkg-
                        config info)]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.5.5]
                   png: yes [version 1.6.17]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                        to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                        to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                        may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                        to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                        to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                        may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
      0 [main] python2.7 2968 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cygEGL-1.dll' (0x420000) is already occupied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 155, in <module>
    result = package.check()
  File "/usr/src/matplotlib-1.4.3/setupext.py", line 503, in check
    additional_info = self.check_requirements()
  File "/usr/src/matplotlib-1.4.3/setupext.py", line 1642, in check_requirements
    ext = self.get_extension()
  File "/usr/src/matplotlib-1.4.3/setupext.py", line 1663, in get_extension
    self.add_flags(ext)
  File "/usr/src/matplotlib-1.4.3/setupext.py", line 1724, in add_flags
    pkg_config.setup_extension(ext, 'pygtk-2.0')
  File "/usr/src/matplotlib-1.4.3/setupext.py", line 296, in setup_extension
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1223, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What can I do next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may possibly come from the backends configuration. I recommend you to disable every backend from `setup.py` but `windowing` that allows you to plot using the `Wx` backend. The libraries are available on Cygwin. You should have no need for Gtk or Tk.